# How to close a text file with the event FormClosed or FormCloing?

Tags: c#, text-files, formclosing

I have the next code:

```
Process open_txt = new Process();
   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      open_txt.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Test.txt";
      open_txt.Start();
   }
```

With this code I open a `.txt` called File `Test.txt` to write on it.

I would like that when I close the form with the mouse (I mean, when I click the little red cross in the upper-right side, in other words, like all of us closes all the windows as well) the `.txt` file called `Test.txt`,also closes.

I know that I need to use the event `FormClosed` or `FormClosing`, but it doesn't work, I have this in this events, but doesn't close the `.txt` file.

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
   open_txt.Close();
}
```

or

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   open_txt.Close();
}
```

How I can close the `.txt` File

Comment: What do you mean by "close the text file"?  Do you mean close the text editor that is showing the text file?  What text editor is it?  How could we possibly answer this question without knowing more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: All you have is a reference to the `Process`, so it seems like the only thing you can do is `Kill` the process.

Comment: I am really confused. `open_text` is a Process. Shouldn't that process take care of closing the file?

Comment: @roryap With "close the text file" I want to say that. I have a program that open a text file, or better know like ".txt" or "notepad file". And I want to close it when the form are closed.

Comment: @roryap I declare open_text like a new Process because I thought, may be work with "open_text.Close()" might work, but doesn't work.

Comment: I think you need to understand a little more about how things work from a process standpoint with an operating system.  Please see D Stanley's answer for a start.

Comment: @Toxantron the class Process, I use it with using System.Diagnostics; Its like use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.EXE");

Comment: @AldoHuerta I understand that but in your comment you reference the executable and in your post a text file.

Comment: @roryap Yeah, I know that, I only been programming for 3 months, so I don't know the basics of this kind of programmation. Sorry If I don't understood your comment. Still I'm a newbie. xD

Comment: @Toxantron Using a non-executable file to start a process will run whatever application is set as the default for that extension.  For Windows PCs Notepad is the default application for `TXT` files but that can be changed by the user.

Comment: @Toxantron You right!!!, pardon My syntaxis mistakes.

Comment: @DStanley true. However wouldn't that program still have to do file handling itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Kill()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method in your `Form1_FormClosing()` method:

```
open_txt.Kill();
```

Comment: Thanks!, It works perfectly, was only one code line. It's embarrassing, that easy that was. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

All you have is a reference to the `Process`, so it seems like the only thing you can do is `Kill()` the process.  That seems fairly heavy-handed, but may do what you want.

It also may have unintended side-effects.  What if the PC used Word to open text files, and when you kill the process you also lose any unsaved changes to other documents?

If you want more control over when the file is closed, then you probably need to embed an editor (or viewer) in your app rather than just farming out to the OS.

Comment: Ok, I don't consider that. But in this application I only use a NotePad file to capture some text and, in this case, I don't want to save the changes made in the NotePad. But I keep it in mind your comment, because later in I would like to save those changes. Thanks for be more specific.

Comment: @AldoHuerta My point is you can't guarantee that Notepad is the app that will be used.  It's fairly easy to change the default app for text files to Word, Notepad++, or some other app.  If you want Notepad to run then change your code to run notepad, passing the name of the text file as an argument.  Even then I think killing the process is heavy-handed.

Comment: Ok, once again thanks, I will change my code to run NotePad.exe.